# How can i assign a USB port to a hyper-v VM?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine

Hey I am looking to assign a USB port to a my hyper-v virtual machine. But I am running into an error. After the last command "Add-VMAssignableDevice..." I get an error at the bottom. Any ideas as to how i can fix this?

````
$vm =   "Client_A"
$locationPath ="Port_#0007.Hub_#0002"
#Set automatic stop action to TurnOff
Set-VM -Name $vm -AutomaticStopAction TurnOff
#Enable Write-Combining on the CPU
Set-VM -GuestControlledCacheTypes $true -VMName $vm
#Configure 32 bit MMIO space
Set-VM -LowMemoryMappedIoSpace 3Gb -VMName $vm
#Configure Greater than 32 bit MMIO space
Set-VM -HighMemoryMappedIoSpace 33280Mb -VMName $vm
#assign to virtual machine
Add-VMAssignableDevice -LocationPath $locationPath -VMName $vm  ```

Error : ```Add-VMAssignableDevice : The specified device 'Port_#0007.Hub_#0002' was not found on server 'DESKTOP-16VOLV0'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-VMAssignableDevice -LocationPath $locationPath -VMName $vm ```
````

Comment: Attaching a USB Device to a Hyper-V guest is fairly tricky.  Try adding the device manually and try this guide to do that .....  https://redmondmag.com/articles/2018/05/17/usb-passthrough-in-hyperv.aspx

Comment: @John sure thing also can you assign usb ports to hyper v vm's - seems like its specifically for USB flash drives.

Comment: Why do you need to assign USB Ports?  You can add devices with what I showed.  Why ports on top of that?  I don't think you can do that with Hyper-V.  Were you able to add a Flash Drive.  I think that might work as well for a USB drive. Hyper-V is restrictive here.

Comment: @John I figured USB ports would be the most intuitive way to do it. You would not have to go through the Discrete Device Assignment process for any new device. But it seems you have to. So make sense :D.... also my device is not supported according to the instructions you shared. Would finding a supported device be the better choice?